Library version conflict python
I have two libraries, and both of them use typing-extensions, but they use different versions of typing-extensions. This conflict is causing an issue as both libraries are needed in one project. How can I resolve this without having to rewrite one of the libraries?
I tried to replace one library, but for my Python goals, there is only one available. And another one - aiogram is exactly needed because the project has been written using it.

Can you please explain your problem a bit more? Probably with some code and error messages.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Conflicting dependencies cannot be magically "resolved". You need to find versions of the libraries that agree on dependencies. Or (at least) one of the libraries must be rewritten to adapt to a common set of dependencies.

One option is to install one version, go to venv_folder/Lib/site-packages, find the package, and edit its folder name and code to a new name, and then install the other version. However, then you may need to edit your other libraries to use the new package name, and this could be what you meant by "rewriting the libraries". If you would like to avoid that...
Another option is to use two virtual environments. This way you can install one package version in each environment, with the corresponding code. It's not pretty, but it could work.
First, set up two folders with venvs as you normally would, and separate your code into parts that use each package version. (You may need to work with small functions that just do a portion of code using one library, separate from code that uses the other library.)
Then, to use code from both venvs, choose one venv (we'll call it VENV A) and format it as a python package (see [https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-the-package-files). After you have done that, you can install it as a module in the other venv (VENV B) by using pip install -e path/to/VENV_A_package in VENV B.
Now you run code or access functions that use one library (VENV A), from scripts that use the other library (VENV B).
